# not sure whether to create new models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making an app with Rails that, among other things,  allows certain types of professionals to create an online profile. So there is an 'association' between the User and Profile model.  I created the Profile model so that I can basically restrict the User model to name and registration information, and keep profile information elsewhere (i.e. 'normalize' the db as I think it's called)

However, these profiles (as is often the case, on LinkedIn, for example) contain a lot of information. For example, there will be a section for Work Experience that sometimes looks like this, where a user can add many different work experiences.

[image]

and then something similar for education

[image]

And many other different types profile information. Note also, that the ability to add to and edit these discrete categories takes place in separate forms. I can add to my work experience without touching education.

My question is, should I try to store all of this information in my Profile model? Or, would you, for example, create a WorkExperience model and do something like Profile :has_many work_experiences?  and something similar with EducationExperience, or is there even another way to do it?

One of my concerns is queries on the DB. For example, in terms of performance, is there going to be much of a difference if, in the show action of the Profile controller, I do queries for WorkExperience.all, Education.all rather than storing all the information in the Profile model?. Another concern is just general code organization for profiles that can become quite large.

Comment: If you're going to have multiple instances of work experience (ie. multiple jobs) or multiple instances of education (high school, bachelors, masters, etc..) for a single `Profile`, you absolutely should have `Profile` with a `has_many` relationship to a new `WorkExperience` and `EducationExperience` model.

Comment: ok, thanks, I think multiple instances are unavoidable. People usually have many degrees and jobs etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have the cleanest code (and decent performance) by splitting out something like Experience (which will belong_to Profile), along with a type column that determines whether it's "work" experience, "education" experience, etc. That's the approach I would take, unless the different types of experience have vastly different columns.

Comment: ok, thanks, I think the 'type' column is reserved in Rails for STI? isn't it. That's what you're suggesting I do then?

Comment: Is each type of experience very different in its columns? Or are they just defined by name? If they're very similar, STI might be overkill.

Comment: It would just keep generic information. company info, job title, type of position, start end dates etc

Comment: In that case, I think you could keep the Experience model generic (without even using STI), because the only difference in the columns would be in how they were labeled in your views.